# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'lik' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

```
echo '<b><h2>Bu Fiyat İçin Oyun Sistemi Önermiyoruz. Bütçenize Yakın Bir Fiyatla 1800TL'lik Sistemimizi Tercih Ediniz.</h2></b><br><br><a href="'. $sistem1800 .'" target="_blank">Tıklayınız.</a><br><br> Şimdiden Hayırlı Olması Dileğiyle, İyi Günler.';
```

I'm giving that error. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to escape the '...
Try this:

```
<?php
echo '<b><h2>Bu Fiyat İçin Oyun Sistemi Önermiyoruz. Bütçenize Yakın Bir Fiyatla 1800TL\'lik Sistemimizi Tercih Ediniz.</h2></b><br><br><a href="'. $sistem1800 .'" target="_blank">Tıklayınız.</a><br><br> Şimdiden Hayırlı Olması Dileğiyle, İyi Günler.';
    ?>
```